# mongodb combine result set to produce single collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called person where I am storing person documents with gender male and female. I want to fetch 2 male and 2 female from single collection in single query in mongodb.
how I can write query to achieve above result?

Comment: This is essentially two queries - one for 2 men and one for 2 women. MongoDB doesn't have a method to use a single query to retrieve N matching one condition and K matching another, in general. Use two queries.

Comment: Please post a sample document, the criteria based on which two people from each group need to be picked. It becomes easy to write answers when you provide the code you tried implementing. Please update the title or edit your question accordingly.